# Activate a buzzer when power goes off

Tags: relay

I am totally new to electronics so I would like to have your help.
The project I would like to build is very simple but yet I don't know the name of the parts that I have to use.
So, I would like to have a relay that will activate a buzzer powered from a 3,6 lithium battery only when the 220 volt of the wall outlet goes off.A reset button would be perfect but not so necessary. 
Please help me with the circuit and the part names. 
Thank you.

Comment: How are you planning to charge this 3.6V Li cell?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest circuit would be a 220V relay and a 3-4.5V buzzer. Connect the battery and buzzer to the N.C. (normally closed) and COM (common) connections of the relay, and connect the relay coil to 220V. The 220V will hold the relay open, and when the electricity goes off the NC and COM connections will be connected internally, powering the buzzer.

Comment: How can I find this kind of relay in market? Is there a name for it ? I suppose there are many kind of relays ...

Comment: It's just a 220V relay. The output handling is so low that it essentially doesn't matter, just make sure that it can handle 5V 1A and you should be set.

Comment: You want a SPDT relay with a 220 Volt coil - the contact rating is not important, as the buzzer will draw very little current.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsZYrH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This avoids having to wire to the mains (avoiding potential safety issues) and provides a 5V source for charging the battery when the 220V is present (you can use a Li battery charging chip such as a Skyworks AAT3681A, which requires no external components).

Comment: Well seems easy to built even for me that I am totally new to electronics...but really what is Q1 and Q2 means on the schematic of the circuit? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Q1 and Q2 are transistors -Q1 is a relatively large through hole TO92 package but Q2 is very tiny surface mount- the required chatpracteristics are hard to find in through hole. Similarly, the Skyworks chip will be very tiny with many leads. You might want to use the relay approach if you're that new and don't have a local friend to help you.